# I'm trying to implement search on Google Maps via Google Places. But google search emerges

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, maps

I'm trying to implement search on Google Maps via Google Places. In my xml I use `AutoCompleteTextView` element. But when I click on `search bar` - google search emerges
why?
is it possible to implement google places with my `searchbar` without `adapter`?

[3sec video screen](https://streamable.com/7hf7ec)

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_1_embed_an_autocompletesupportfragment):

> To add an AutocompleteSupportFragment to your app, take the following steps:
>
> 1. Add a fragment to your activity's XML layout.
> 2. Add a listener to your activity or fragment.

**Layout**:

```xml
<fragment android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
  />
```

**Code**:

```kotlin
 // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
    val autocompleteFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment)
            as AutocompleteSupportFragment

    // Specify the types of place data to return.
    autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(listOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME))

    // Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object : PlaceSelectionListener {
        override fun onPlaceSelected(place: Place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: ${place.name}, ${place.id}")
        }

        override fun onError(status: Status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: $status")
        }
    })
```

Comment: unfortunatelly no. all that I found is - You can create a custom search UI as an alternative to the UI provided by the autocomplete widget. To do this, your app must get place predictions programmatically. Your app can get a list of predicted place names and/or addresses from the autocomplete API by calling PlacesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(), passing a FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest object with the following parameters.    from here - https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_widget

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: to read docs, to write code and to share code on medium.   I wrote this adapter already.  Briefly - need to write my own recycler view below search bar and load there results of API's work.  Year ago google places completely changed API and don't support old version at all. I didnot find any materials on Internet. All stuff - either on Java or for old API